# Product links in menu structure

Tags: magento-1.7, menu

I've noticed that links structure in menu changes in one subcategory. By default thay are displayed as human friendly permalinks, which is ok.

In subcategory links are changed to i.e.: `/catalog/product/view/id/16/s/permalink/category/8/`

I was trying to debug it - without success. What can cause this error?

Comment: Make sure your url rewrite index is up to date.

Comment: That didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Magento defaults the URL to that structure if it doesn't find a URL key for that category.

Run  **Catalog URL Rewrites** (*System -> Index Management*) and clear the cache.

Comment: That's too obvious ;-) Clearing Magento Cache and running re-indexing was the first think I did, but that didn't solve the problem. Same menu element have two different link format on different pages.

Comment: check your core_url_rewrites table, do you have any record in there for that category?